# Does a completed kubernetes pod still reserves the required resources?

Tags: kubernetes

If I have a `CronJob` the has `requests.memory` of, let's say, `100Mi`, when the pod finishes and enter on `Completed` state, does it still "reserves" that amount of memory, or are the requested resources freed up?

Both [Jobs docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) and [Pod Lifecycle docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/) don't specify what happens after the pods in on `Completed` phase.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Nope, Kubernetes no more reserves memory or CPU once *Pods* are marked *completed*.

Providing you this example using a local `minikube` instance.

## the Job manifest

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: test-job
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - date
        image: busybox
        name: test-job
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 200Mi
      restartPolicy: Never
status: {}
```

## the Node describe output

```
# kubectl describe node|grep -i mem -C 5
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests     Limits
  --------           --------     ------
  cpu                755m (37%)   0 (0%)
  memory             190Mi (10%)  340Mi (19%)
```

## Applying the job and then describing the node

```
# kubectl create -f job.yaml && kubectl describe node | grep -i mem -C 5
job.batch/test-job created
(...)
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests     Limits
  --------           --------     ------
  cpu                755m (37%)   0 (0%)
  memory             390Mi (22%)  340Mi (19%)
```

## describe again the Node after the Job completion

```
# kubectl describe node | grep -i mem -C 5
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests     Limits
  --------           --------     ------
  cpu                755m (37%)   0 (0%)
  memory             190Mi (10%)  340Mi (19%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)       0 (0%)
```

Comment: Pods in failed phase does not seem to reserve resources as well.